# Open Form next to Parent Form

Tags: c#

I have a form, which spawns another form. However it is un-coordinated and pretty darn ugly. So I ask, how do I spawn the form brushed against the parent form(first one).

Sorry if I sound wierd, but I just can't find the words to describe it.

Answer (score 6):

From `Form1`

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
form2.Location = new Point(this.Left + this.Width, this.Top);
```

optionally you may want to match height too

```
form2.Height = this.Height;
```

Comment: That worked for my first form, but my second form spawns on top of it. How can I make my second form spawn below the first one?

Comment: @Totally: this makes what you asked in your question and also suggests you how to implement something more convoluted. If you need more help, you should expand your answer and describe what you're trying to accomplish (perhaps using pictures/screenshots)