# Show Form side-by-side owner Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form. If someone presses a button, I want to show a second form "attached" to the original form, meaning that its left side is at the right side of the original form and they have the same height. In other words: they touch each other.

An answer seems to be [Open Form next to Parent Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204189/open-form-next-to-parent-form)

However, there is a gap between the images. I want them to be exactly next to each other

[image]

**main form:**

```
private void ShowOtherForm()
{
    using (var form = new OtherForm())
    {
        var dlgResult = form.ShowDialog(this);
        ProcessDlgResult(dlgResult);
    }
}
```

**Other form, event handler Load**

```
private void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // show this form attached to the right side of my owner:
    this.Location = new Point(this.Owner.Right, this.Owner.Top);
    this.Height = this.Owner.Height;
}
```

Comment: Invisible border. See [SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.framebordersize) and friends (`SystemInformation.Border3DSize`, `SystemInformation.BorderMultiplierFactor` etc.).

Comment: It could be interesting to read the notes (Remarks sections) of [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect), [DwmGetWindowAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute) ([DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute) -> `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS`) and [Controlling non-client region rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/composition-ovw#controlling-non-client-region-rendering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `ClientSize` and `Location`

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var owner = this.Owner;
   Location = new Point(owner.Location.X + owner.ClientSize.Width, owner.Location.Y);
   Height = owner.Height;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. I don't know why your were voted down